# Angularjs REST api post method "update" error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest

I'm trying CRUD operation in AngularJS [frontend] and Node.js [backend]

Error : When I click the **edit** button the **data display** in the **form field** and change the data then click the **submit** button it display the **data** in **alert** once again I click the **submit** button it **doesn't** show the **alert**

here the code I used:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('test').controller('schedule', function (
  $scope, $http) {

        var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.details = data;
        })
        .error(function () {
            $scope.error = "error";
        });

      $scope.edit= function(data){
          $scope.data=data;
        });

      }
      $scope.update= function(data){
          $scope.update=data;
           var d=angular.toJson(data);
           alert(d);
          // $http.post(url, data, config) //add your logic
          // .success(function(data, status) {
          //   if (status == 201) {
          //     $scope.message = data;
          //     alert(status);
          //   }
          // })
          // .error(function(data, status) {
          //   if (status == 401) {
          //     $scope.message = status;
          //   } else if (status == 400) {
          //     $scope.message = status;
          //   }
          //   $scope.message=status;
          // });

      }

});
```

here the view part
**index.html**

```
<div layout="row">

<div flex="50">
  <table >
    <tr ng-repeat="data in details">
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ data.title }}</td>
        <td>  <md-button   ng-click="edit(data)"> edit </md-button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<div flex="50">
  <h1>Edit</h1>
  <div class="border" layout=column class="md-raised" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="auto" >
    <md-input-container >
      <label>
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
      id
      </label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.id" name="id">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="nomargin">
      <label>
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-open"></i>
        title</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.title" name="title" required>
      </md-input-container>

      <md-button ng-click="update(data)"> submit </md-button>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS9G8.jpg)

Comment: this could be causing your issue: $scope.update= function(data){
          $scope.update=data; try using a different variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get below error

```
TypeError: v2.update is not a function
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:213:110), <anonymous>:4:222)
    at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:254:74)
    at r.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:133:313)
    at r.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:134:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:254:126)
    at If (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:35:367)
    at HTMLButtonElement.Hf.d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:35:314)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12520(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9292r.$apply @ angular.js:16157(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23618If @ angular.js:3346Hf.d @ angular.js:3334
```

because update is no longer a function when you set $scope as said by @Judson Terrell

```
$scope.update= function(data){
          $scope.newData=data;
           var d=angular.toJson(data);
           alert(d);
          // $http.post(url, data, config) //add your logic
          // .success(function(data, status) {
          //   if (status == 201) {
          //     $scope.message = data;
          //     alert(status);
          //   }
          // })
          // .error(function(data, status) {
          //   if (status == 401) {
          //     $scope.message = status;
          //   } else if (status == 400) {
          //     $scope.message = status;
          //   }
          //   $scope.message=status;
          // });

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.update= function(data){
          $scope.update=data;
```

When you set $scope.update to an object, its no longer a function ;) Try creating a different data placeholder

```
$scope.update= function(data){
              $scope.myData=data;
```

Comment: Why didn't I get accepted answer? I answered exactly the issue. :-(